# Do I really have to use special primer to encapsulate lead paint?

Tags: paint, lead, dust, encapsulation

I live in a 100 year old house with my wife and 6 year old.   I’ve recently gone down the lead paint rabbit hole online, as I realized that some of the trim in my home has lead paint.  Usually under several layers of newer non-lead paint.

There are a couple of spots that have some chipping.  Nothing major.  Usually a window frame with a little inch-long spot that’s chipping off.  I understand the dangers of lead paint, and I also understand that one of the recommended ways of dealing with lead paint is encapsulation.   Unfortunately, I live in CA where they seem to not want regular folks like myself to be able to buy encapsulating primer.  Perhaps to discourage DIY remediation.

I understand that, but I also know how expensive proper remediation can get.  And it seems like massive overkill for me if I’ve essentially got a handful of touch ups to do.

This leads me to my question, and I can’t seem to find a clear answer online…

I keep seeing that special encapsulating primer is the only thing you can use to properly encapsulate.  If I’m covering the chipped off trim spots w/ several layers of quality primer (stix), and layers of quality latex paint on top of that - how is this not sufficient for encapsulation?  Is the lead dust going to sneak out from under the layers of regular primer and paint and fly everywhere?   Someone set me straight on this.

Comment: The main danger with lead paint is eating of it by small children and by sanding, then eating/breathing the dust .  No sanding or eating, can basically leave it alone.

Comment: Well, painted parts that move (ie, windows, sticky doors) create dust with lead in it; kids touch dust; kids stick their fingers in their mouth. So it’s not just sanding and chips.

Comment: And this seems to be readily available (though I didn’t try the checkout process). https://www.homedepot.com/p/ECOBOND-LBP-Lead-Defender-PRO-1-Gal-Off-White-Flat-Lead-Based-Paint-Treatment-and-Sealant-ECO-LBP-1001-P/202830398

Comment: Also - it seems like if friction was rubbing off spots of paint, an encapsulating primer wouldn’t do much good either.

Comment: @crip659 I think I read or heard that lead paint chips taste sweet so that's another concern if not all the paint is in good condition.

Comment: The expensive stuff is the stuff that the manufacturer has tested thoroughly and is willing to guarantee will work if properly used.  Will other things work?  Probably.  Are some of the cheaper products exactly the same thing, just labeled differently and the manufacturer's insurance won't cover it if it fails?  Probably. Are you going to have trouble getting definitive answers without testing it yourself due to liability issues?  Probably.

Comment: @Perkins Excellent points.  And it might also explain why it's hard for 'regular folks' to get these products.  The manufacturers likely have specific requirements around the application of their products which are the basis of their effectiveness claims.

Comment: I grew up in a 100-year-old house and can attest that the lead paint chips were salty-sweet delicious. My parents heat-gunned all of the paint off of the windows and floor trim starting with my bedroom when they caught one of us kids putting the paint chips from the windowsill in our mouths.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: According to *The Disappearing Spoon*, the ancient Romans used lead acetate as an artificial sweetener.  Probably wouldn't be approved by the FDA today, though.

Comment: I had a friend who bought a house after the previous owner destroyed himself with lead paint while renovating. Obviously not your case BUT the dangers are real.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon what did your friend do with the house?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the Romans would boil (reduce) grape juice in lead pots to make a sweetener—lead acetate.

Comment: @Huesmann The house had been remediated by the time he bought it. He went on to die very young from unrelated causes :-(.

Answer (score 16):

The main risk with lead paint is disturbing it, the encapsulating primer can stick to weathered surfaces without the need to sand the surface first,

If the surface you are painitng is a fresh surface (as it is under a chip) then anything that sticks to the surface is suitable.  the lead is not going to migrate through layers of paint

Answer (score 6):

One recurring theme here is "pop" home hazards being treated like plutonium, while genuine ones that will kill you being completely ignored.  The person in a fuss about asbestos will later ask how to eliminate an annoying GFCI or how to change their dryer/range outlet to 3-prong.  People suck at risk assessment unless they go to school for that.

It helps to understand the risk (or non-risk for you) by understanding how the hazard became "pop" i.e. got all the media coverage.  In the 1940s there was a strong eugenics movement that did involve an actual shooting war in Europe. Scientists wanted to debunk "eugenics" as a concept, but a sticking point was solid data showing poor development in minority children. As scientists pulled on that thread, they found minority children were far more likely to live in (poorly maintained rental) homes **with peeling paint**. And toddlers would eat the paint peels or gnaw on window sills.

This is the threat vector that caused all the ruckus, to which you are reacting today.

So now you know: train children to not gnaw on trim (I don't imagine that will be a big problem), and do not tolerate peeling paint.

Now let's talk about the clear and present danger of lead:  paint prep. The threat is ingestion (either as inhaled or swallowed dust).  So do your sanding wet. Contain your chips and dust. Dispose of properly.  Wear PPE (we're talking N95 mask).

And do paint prep.  Falling short on paint prep only means more paint failure and more rework.

Paint salesmen of course would like you to use special primer and special paint. But it's really about the stuff I stated above.  Lead isn't going to soak through any modern paint and menace you.

Answer (score 0):

Some types of paint and primer do not adhere well to lead-based paint and will simply flake off after a surprisingly short time. You want to make sure that whatever you put on will stick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Your 6 year old is unlikely to eat any chips that flake off.  Just use any primer/paint to cover it up.  It is not a big deal if ingested in tiny quantities.

Comment: Lead paint actually tastes sweet, so children enjoy eating it. The OP's child may well eat the paint chips that flake off. Further, scientists have become increasingly concerned about the long-term impact of lead on the brain, especially in small children. There is currently considered to be no safe blood level of this element. Perhaps the risk in this case is small, but I would personally err on the side of caution.

Comment: @Bob: I wonder if a primer containing something like bitrex (a denaturing agent that's extremely bitter) might reduce the hazards from lead paint.